# Fragment has leaked although it's attached

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

i use BottomNavigationView on MainActivity with 4 Fragments. Also, i use LeakCanary to check memory leaks and i got this Fragment leak although it isn't detached and its hosting Activity isn't destroyed.

```
* org.kafora.apps.qutoof.ui.main.home.HomeFragment has leaked:
* static ActivityThread.sCurrentActivityThread
* ↳ ActivityThread.mActivities
* ↳ ArrayMap.mArray
* ↳ array Object[].[3]
* ↳ ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord.activity
* ↳ MainActivity.!(mHomeFragment)!
* ↳ HomeFragment
```

The leak trace details:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kd82el7z_82AVLfYDrhfEW7tV50kcrQP/view?usp=sharing

and here's `MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends MediaBaseActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        , BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private BrowseFragment mBrowseFragment;
    private HomeFragment mHomeFragment;
    private LibraryFragment mLibraryFragment;
    private ReminderFragment mReminderFragment;

    private Unbinder unbinder;
    @BindView(R.id.parentView)
    View parentView;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.bottom_nav_view) BottomNavigationView bottomNavView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        displayInitialHomeFragment();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setupBottomNavigationView(); 
    }
    private HomeFragment getHomeFragment(){
        if(mHomeFragment == null) mHomeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
        return mHomeFragment;
    }

    private BrowseFragment getBrowseFragment(){
        if(mBrowseFragment == null) mBrowseFragment = BrowseFragment.newInstance();
        return mBrowseFragment;
    }
    private LibraryFragment getLibraryFragment(){
        if(mLibraryFragment == null) mLibraryFragment = LibraryFragment.newInstance();
        return mLibraryFragment;
    }
    private ReminderFragment getReminderFragment(){
        if(mReminderFragment == null) mReminderFragment = ReminderFragment.newInstance();
        return mReminderFragment;
    }

    private void displayInitialHomeFragment() {
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container) == null) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, getHomeFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    private void displaySelectedFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container)) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public void setupBottomNavigationView() {
      bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
      bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                displaySelectedFragment(getHomeFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.browse:
                displaySelectedFragment(getBrowseFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.library:
                displaySelectedFragment(getLibraryFragment());
                return true;
            case R.id.reminder:
                displaySelectedFragment(getReminderFragment());
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbinder.unbind();
        mHomeFragment= null;
        mBrowseFragment = null;
        mReminderFragment = null;
        mLibraryFragment = null;
    }
}
```

What is the reason of this memory leak?

Comment: Have you used a profiler to look at your allocations? It could be a false positive

Comment: Don't save fragment reference in mHomeFragment or if it can't be escaped then always free up mHomeFragment when you are replacing HomeFragment with any other fragment.

Basically, you should not hold any fragment reference once you have replaced it with a new fragment.